# Is it possible to use a laser to prevent a magnetic field from entering a given area?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, photons

Is it possible to bend a magnetic field away from an area with a laser, after all, photons are electromagnetic, so couldn't they disrupt the magnetic field, bending it away from a area? If so, how could I do this? I need to block a refrigerator magnet's magnetic field repeatedly.

Comment: Photons don't generally interact with other photons. They pass through the same area and interfere when measured, but don't collide in any meaningful sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. Electromagnetism is a linear theory, which means that if you have two independent solutions to two independent sources (i.e. the magnetic field caused by the fridge and the light field produced by the laser) then the total solution will be the sum of the two independent responses.

The *only* way around that fact is to use [materials with a nonlinear response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics), which do exhibit behaviour like [optical rectification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_rectification), but this tends to require much higher intensities than would be practical at a device level. There's plenty of technologies around for magnetic shielding, given the frequency with which it's required, but optical magnetic shielding isn't really one of them.

Comment: What kind of technologies are out there? I need to shield the magnetic field repeatedly on/off again at a frequency of about 30ghz...

Comment: @baconcat Did you try [looking in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding#Magnetic_shielding)?